# Unresolved reference: this@SplashScreen while accessing SplashScreen from inner class

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to access SplashScreen activity from an inner class as shown below. But I cant resolve this@SplashScreen

```
class SplashScreen : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)
        verifyPermissions()

    }

    private class SplashTimerTask : TimerTask() {

        override fun run() {
            val mainIntent = Intent(this@SplashScreen, LoginActivity::class.java)
            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(mainIntent)
            this@SplashScreen.finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
private class SplashTimerTask(val splash: SplashScreen) : TimerTask() {

    override fun run() {
        val mainIntent = Intent(splash, LoginActivity::class.java)
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(mainIntent)
        splash.finish()
    }
}
```

or

```
inner class SplashTimerTask : TimerTask() {

        override fun run() {
            val mainIntent = Intent(this@SplashScreen, LoginActivity::class.java)
            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(mainIntent)
            this@SplashScreen.finish()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Option 1 resolves the issue, but a new issue appears with 
startActivity(mainIntent)  

Type mismatch.
Required: Context
Found: Intent

Comment: i changed startActivity(mainIntent)
 into -> startActivity(splash, mainIntent, null) fixed my issue..

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

this could be resolved by changing the SplashTimerTask like below

```
    private class SplashTimerTask(val splash: SplashScreen) : TimerTask() {

    override fun run() {
        val mainIntent = Intent(splash, LoginActivity::class.java)
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(splash, mainIntent, null)
        splash.finish()
    }
}
```

and calling in SplashScreen like below

```
_splashTimerTask = SplashTimerTask(this@SplashScreen)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from passing the parent class as a parameter (the verbose, sloppy option), and marking the timer class `inner`, the third option is an anonymous class:

```
private val splashTimerTask = object: TimerTask() {

    override fun run() {
        val mainIntent = Intent(this@SplashScreen, LoginActivity::class.java)
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(mainIntent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

A fourth option is to use a coroutine instead of a Timer and TimerTask:

```
private fun openLoginActivity(delay: Long) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(delay)
        val mainIntent = Intent(this@SplashScreen, LoginActivity::class.java)
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(mainIntent)
        finish()
    }
}
```